# C# Wrapper for Encoding.com?

Tags: c#, encoding

I'm looking for a C# wrapper for the web services of encoding.com. I found a [PHP wrapper](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/laboratory/library/ZendL/Encoding/Encoding.php), but no C#.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: it would be cool to integrate them in my application, and then become an affiliate - do they have such program?

Comment: Hi, Im also looking for this. Found anything?
/Rune

Comment: nothing found so far. it look like we will write one ourselves when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://api.encoding.com/#C

Comment: I meant something more comprehensive. Not just some lines of code but a class that actually works with them. Thanks anyway.